# POST <option>text instead of value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to submit the text instead of the value of the option.

I have dependent SELECTS and that's why I cannot put the actual text in the value field.

This is my dependent select

```
<select class="form-control" name="Category" id="Category" >
                <option value="1">Restaurants</option>
                <option value="2">Coffee Shops, Patisseries, Bakeries</option>
                <option value="3">Bars and Pubs</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="SubCategory" id="SubCategory">
<option value="1">Home Made Food</option>
                <option value="1">Gardens and Outdoor</option>
                <option value="1">Food Delivery</option>
                <option value="2">Coffee Shop</option>
                <option value="2">Patisserie</option>
                <option value="2">Bakery</option>
                <option value="3">Bar</option>
                <option value="3">Pub</option>
                <option value="3">Wine Bar</option>
                <option value="3">Life Music</option>
                <option value="3">Night club</option>
</select>
```

and this is the JS I am using

```
var $Category = $( '#Category' ),
    $SubCategory = $( '#SubCategory' ),
    $options = $SubCategory.find( 'option' );
$Category.on( 'change', function() {
    $SubCategory.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );
```

I know that I can аssign the text within the `<option>` to a hidden field and use it to submit the text and for that, I can use this

```
<input id="category_text" type = "hidden" name = "category_text" value = "" />
```

And firing it with `onchange="setTextField(this)"` on the `<select>`

Using

```
function setTextField(ddl) {
    document.getElementById('category_text').value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

So the problem is that when I use the `onchange="setTextField(this)"` it brakes the whole js for the dependent selects.

Any idea of how to combine `onchange="setTextField(this)"` with

```
var $Category = $( '#Category' ),
    $SubCategory = $( '#SubCategory' ),
    $options = $SubCategory.find( 'option' );
$Category.on( 'change', function() {
    $SubCategory.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );
```

so it adds the option text to the hidden input?
I need to get the text from both Category and SubCategory

Comment: don't use value for that. use a custom data attr for that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `change` handler is removing all the options from `$SubCategory` that aren't related to the selected category. Then if you change the category again, the subcategory options for the new category are no longer there to put back.

Instead of using `.html()` to replace the contents of the `$SubCategory` `<select>`, you should just hide or show the options.

```
$Category.on( 'change', function() {
    var category = this.value;
    $SubCategory.find("option").attr("hidden", function() {
        return this.value != category;
    });
} ).trigger( 'change' );
```

There's no problem with `setTextField()`. But as a comment said, a better idea would be to use a different attribute to relate subcategories to categories, rather than the `value` field.

```
<option value="1">Home Made Food</option>
    <option data-category="1" value="Gardens and Outdoor">Gardens and Outdoor</option>
    <option data-category="1" value="Food Delivery">Food Delivery</option>
    <option data-category="2" value="Coffee Shop">Coffee Shop</option>
    <option data-category="2" value="Patisserie">Patisserie</option>
    <option data-category="2" value="Bakery">Bakery</option>
    <option data-category="3" value="Bar">Bar</option>
    <option data-category="3" value="Pub">Pub</option>
    <option data-category="3" value="Wine Bar">Wine Bar</option>
    <option data-category="3" value="Life Music">Life Music</option>
    <option data-category="3" value="Night club">Night club</option>
</select>
```

Then you can use `this.dataset.category` instead of `this.value` in the above code.

Comment: Do I have to use data-category="1" on both category and subcategory as eventually, I will need both values from Category and SubCategory?

Comment: I thought the problem was only with the subcategory, since it has duplicate values.

Comment: It is both, I guess I didn't mention that in my initial question

Comment: Of course you can use `data-category` in both places.

Comment: I tried that already. However, when I use it that way it doesn't hide all options that are not within the corresponding data-category, but shows all options

Comment: Did you change to `var category = this.dataset.category;`?

Comment: when I use var category = this.dataset.category; the menu shows only the first subcategory option, no matter which category I choose

Comment: Oh, it should be `this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.category`

Comment: with that it works, I have also added return this.dataset.category != category; It is strange because the default(start) option for all subcategories is the last selected. so if in Restaurants I select Homemade food, and then change to Bars and Pubs it will show me Homemade food and then the other options in that bars and pubs category. The last selected stays like you usually have -- choose an option --

Comment: Any idea why it is remembering the last selected option until you select another?

Comment: Nothing in this code changes the value of `selectedIndex` in the subcategory menu after hiding and showing options.

Comment: Any idea how to do it?